# How to fill Canvas with rectangles without edge aliasing artifacts in WinRT

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime, wpf-controls, winrt-xaml

I'm writing simple puzzle game, where puzzle is a board made of squares. Number of squares per X and per Y is fixed. I want puzzle to uniformly scale to arbitrary size to adapt to user's screen, filling all space left by game controls.

Here's sample XAML, that displays the issue. Viewbox is used to do automatic scaling.

```
  <Viewbox>
    <Canvas Width="320" Height="240" Background="Black">
      <Border
          Width="20" Height="20"
          Background="Red"
          >
        <Border.RenderTransform>
          <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
        </Border.RenderTransform>
      </Border>
      <Border
          Width="20" Height="20"
          Background="Red"
          >
        <Border.RenderTransform>
          <TranslateTransform X="20" Y="0" />
        </Border.RenderTransform>
      </Border>
      <Border
          Width="20" Height="20"
          Background="Red"
          >
        <Border.RenderTransform>
          <TranslateTransform X="40" Y="0" />
        </Border.RenderTransform>
      </Border>
    </Canvas>
  </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

Problem appears in the actual application, but can also be observed in Visual Studio XAML designer. If you open this file and set scaling to 111%, 1px width vertical black gaps will appear between rectangles. I assume this happens because of aliasing on edges.

[image: aliasing screenshot]

So far I tried to set CacheMode="BitmapCache" and/or UseLayoutRounding="False" on Canvas. It did not help.

How to get rid of this rendering artifact?

P.S. sorry, SO's parser cut opening tag. Here's link to PasteBin: http://pastebin.com/qtre6XSg

Comment: Set your background color to Red and it's fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you add a ScaleTransform="1.01" then the edges will overlap. Sorry for this answer, but I think, given how it works, this might be your best solution.

Comment: It does not really help. Just reduces amount of cases, when lines appear, and increases number of cases, when squares look like they have different sizes.

Comment: Setting Width and Height to 20.5 helped though

Comment: At higher resolution, it now looks bad

Comment: I'm frustrated for you on this one. Sounds like you need to embrace the problem and not fight it. Just create a margin / padding between the items in your game. Otherwise, you're all up hill.